# Is there a way to configure which browser (Edge vs Chrome) is used at the application level instead of OS level?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I would like Chrome to be my default browser for most cases, with the exception of MS Outlook.  When using MS Outlook I would like to open links using the MS Edge browser.

Most of my day I want to be in Chrome with my client's MS Office 365. few times a day I check my employer email using MS Outlook and want links clicked in Outlook to open in edge (which is signed into their MS Office 365 universe).

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of Outlook offer an option to open links in e-mails specifically in Edge. You can activate this option at:

> File -> Options -> Advanced -> (scroll way down to) Link Handling -> Open Hyperlinks from Outlook in

Comment: Thank you; I will try it out and mark correct if it works.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Outlook uses your system's default browser to open hyperlinks. As far as I know, there is no way to have Outlook uses a different browser other than the one set as default on your computer system.